# Calculate $I=\int_0^{1}\frac{1+x}{x^2+x+1}\log\left({\frac{x}{1-x}}\right)\,\mathrm dx$ without using complex analysis

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Calculate $$I=\int_0^{1}\frac{1+x}{x^2+x+1}\log\left({\frac{x}{1-x}}\right)\,\mathrm dx$$
>   without using complex analysis.

How to calculate without using the residue theorem?

The **correct** answer is
$$-\frac{1}{8}\ln^23+\frac{\pi^2}{72}-\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{36}\ln3$$

---

This integral is solved using complex analysis in the French book Gilbert Demengel "Balades sur les chemins du champs complexe"page 228 (exemple 4.53.)
The answer in the book $$\frac{1}{8}\ln^23-\frac{\pi^2}{72}-\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{36}\ln3$$ is **wrong**.

Comment: The first answer is correct, the second is wrong(given in the book)

Comment: Sorry, correction read $$-\frac{1}{8}\ln^23$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
I=&\int_0^{1}\frac{(1+x)\ln{\frac{x}{1-x}}}{x^2+x+1}dx\\
=&\ \frac12\int_0^1 \frac{\ln{\frac{x}{1-x}}}{x^2+x+1}
 + \frac{(2x+1)\ln x}{x^2+x+1}-\frac{(2x+1)\ln (1-x)}{x^2+x+1} \ dx\\
=&\ \frac12(I_1+I_2-I_3)
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
I_1&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln{\frac{x}{1-x}}}{x^2+x+1}\overset{\frac {\sqrt3x}{1-x}\to x}{dx}
=\frac1{2\sqrt3}\int_0^\infty \frac{-\ln3}{x^2+\sqrt3x+1}dx
=-\frac{\pi\ln3}{6\sqrt3}\\
I_2&=\int_0^1 \frac{(2x+1)\ln x}{x^2+x+1}{dx}
= 2\Re \text{Li}_2\left(e^{i\frac{2\pi}3}\right)=-\frac{\pi^2}9\\
 I_3&=\int_0^1 \frac{(2x+1)\ln (1-x)}{x^2+x+1}\overset{x\to 1-x}{dx}
= \int_0^1 \frac{(1-\frac23x)\ln x}{\frac13x^2-x+1}{dx}\\
&=-2\Re \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1+i/\sqrt3}2\right)=\frac14\ln^23-\frac{5\pi^2}{36}
\end{align}
The identity $\Re\text{Li}_2(\frac{1+ia}2)=\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\frac12(\tan^{-1}a)^2-\frac18\ln^2\frac{1+a^2}4$ is used in evaluating $I_3$ and $\Re\text{Li}_2(e^{ia})=-\frac{\pi^2}{12}+\frac14(\pi-a)^2 $ in $I_2$. Substitute $I_1$, $I_2$ and $I_3$ into $I$ to obtain
$$I=\frac{\pi^2}{72}-\frac{\pi}{12\sqrt3}\ln3  -\frac{1}{8}\ln^23$$

Answer (score 7):

(What is following is a complete solution)

Let $\displaystyle J=\int_{\sqrt{3}}^{+\infty}\tfrac{\ln(t-\sqrt{3})}{1+t^2} dt$

Perform the change of variable $u=\arctan t$,

$\displaystyle J=\int_{\tfrac{\pi}{3}}^{\tfrac{\pi}{2}}\ln(\tan(t)-\sqrt{3})dt=\int_{\tfrac{\pi}{3}}^{\tfrac{\pi}{2}}\ln\left(\tfrac{\sin\left(t-\tfrac{\pi}{3}\right)}{\cos(t)\cos\left(\tfrac{\pi}{3}\right)}\right)dt$

Therefore,

$\displaystyle J=\int_{\tfrac{\pi}{3}}^{\tfrac{\pi}{2}}\ln\left(\sin\left(t-\tfrac{\pi}{3}\right)\right)dt-\int_{\tfrac{\pi}{3}}^{\tfrac{\pi}{2}}\ln\left(\cos t\right)dt+\tfrac{\pi}{6}\ln 2$

Perform the change of variable $u=t-\tfrac{\pi}{3}$ in the first integral and $u=\tfrac{\pi}{2}-t$ in the second one.

Therefore,

$\displaystyle J=\int_0^{\tfrac{\pi}{6}}\ln\left(\sin t\right)dt-\int_0^{\tfrac{\pi}{6}}\ln\left(\sin t\right)dt+\tfrac{\pi}{6}\ln 2=\tfrac{\pi}{6}\ln 2$

PS:

$\displaystyle A=\int_0^1 \dfrac{\log\left(\dfrac{x}{1-x}\right)}{1+x+x^2}dx=-\int_0^1 \dfrac{\log\left(\dfrac{1}{x}-1\right)}{1+x+x^2}dx$

Perform the change of variable $y=\dfrac{1}{x}$

$\displaystyle A=-\int_1^{+\infty} \dfrac{\log\left(x-1\right)}{1+x+x^2}dx$

$\displaystyle A=-\dfrac{4}{3}\int_1^{+\infty} \dfrac{\log\left(x-1\right)}{1+\left(\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}x+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2}dx$

Perform the change of variable $y=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}x+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$

Therefore,

$\displaystyle A=-\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\int_{\sqrt{3}}^{+\infty}\dfrac{\log\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x-\dfrac{3}{2}\right)}{1+x^2}dx$

Therefore,

$\displaystyle A=-\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\int_{\sqrt{3}}^{+\infty}\dfrac{\log\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}{1+x^2}dx-\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\int_{\sqrt{3}}^{+\infty}\dfrac{\log\left(x-\sqrt{3}\right)}{1+x^2}dx$

Therefore,

$\displaystyle A=-\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\times \dfrac{\pi}{6}\log\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)-\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\times J$

Finally,

$A=-\dfrac{\pi\log 3}{6\sqrt{3}}$

PS2:

One more step...

$B=\displaystyle \int_0^1 \dfrac{(2x+1)\log(1-x)}{1+x+x^2}dx$

$B=\displaystyle \left[\left(\log(1+x+x^2)-\log 3\right)\log(1-x)\right]_0^1+\int_0^1 \dfrac{\log(1+x+x^2)-\log 3}{1-x}dx$

$\displaystyle B=\int_0^1 \dfrac{\log(1+x+x^2)-\log 3}{1-x}dx$

Perform the change of variable $y=1-x$,

$\displaystyle B=\int_0^1 \dfrac{\log(x^2-3x+3)-\log 3}{x}dx=\int_0^1 \dfrac{\log\left(\dfrac{1}{3}x^2-x+1\right)}{x}dx$

Define for $\dfrac{3}{4}\leq a\leq 1$

$\displaystyle F(a)=\int_0^1 \dfrac{\log\left(\dfrac{a}{3}x^2-x+1\right)}{x}dx$

Note that $\displaystyle F\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)=\int_0^1 \dfrac{2\log\left(1-\dfrac{x}{2}\right)}{x}dx=-2Li_2\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)=(\log 2)^2-\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$

and $F(1)=B$

$\displaystyle F'(a)=\int_0^1 \dfrac{x}{ax^2-3x+3}dx$

$F'(a)=\left[\dfrac{\log(ax^2-3x+3)}{2a}+\dfrac{\arctan\left(\dfrac{2ax-3}{\sqrt{12a-9}}\right)}{a\sqrt{\dfrac{4}{3}a-1}}\right]_0^1$

Therefore,

$\displaystyle \int_{\tfrac{3}{4}}^1 F'(a)da=\left[\dfrac{\log(a)^2}{4}\right]_{\tfrac{3}{4}}^{1}-\left[\dfrac{\log(3)\log(a)}{2}\right]_{\tfrac{3}{4}}^{1}+\int_{\tfrac{3}{4}}^{1} \left[\dfrac{\arctan\left(\dfrac{2a-3}{\sqrt{12a-9}}\right)}{a\sqrt{\dfrac{4}{3}a-1}}+\dfrac{\arctan\left(\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{12a-9}}\right)}{a\sqrt{\dfrac{4}{3}a-1}}\right]da$

Perform the change of variable $y=\sqrt{\dfrac{4}{3}a-1}$, one obtains:

$\displaystyle \int_{\tfrac{3}{4}}^1 F'(a)da=-\dfrac{\left(\log\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)\right)^2}{4}+\dfrac{\log(3)\log\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)}{2}+\int_0^{\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}} \left[\dfrac{2\arctan\left(\dfrac{a^2-1}{2a}\right)}{1+a^2}+\dfrac{2\arctan\left(\dfrac{1}{a}\right)}{1+a^2}\right]da$

$\displaystyle \int_{\tfrac{3}{4}}^1 F'(a)da=-\dfrac{\left(\log\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)\right)^2}{4}+\dfrac{\log(3)\log\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)}{2}+2\int_0^{\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}} \dfrac{\arctan\left(\dfrac{2a}{1-a^2}\right)-\arctan\left(a\right)}{1+a^2}da$

$\displaystyle \int_{\tfrac{3}{4}}^1 F'(a)da=-\dfrac{\left(\log\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)\right)^2}{4}+\dfrac{\log(3)\log\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)}{2}+2\int_0^{\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}} \dfrac{2\arctan\left(a\right)-\arctan\left(a\right)}{1+a^2}da$

$\displaystyle \int_{\tfrac{3}{4}}^1 F'(a)da=-\dfrac{\left(\log\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)\right)^2}{4}+\dfrac{\log(3)\log\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)}{2}+\left[\arctan(a)^2\right]_0^{\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}$

$\displaystyle \int_{\tfrac{3}{4}}^1 F'(a)da=\dfrac{\log(3)^2}{4}-\log(2)^2+\dfrac{\pi^2}{36}=F(1)-F\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)$

Therefore,

$B=F(1)=\dfrac{\log(3)^2}{4}+\dfrac{\pi^2}{36}-\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$

$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \dfrac{x\log(1-x)}{1+x+x^2}dx=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(B-\int_0^1 \dfrac{\log(1-x)}{1+x+x^2}\right)dx=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(B+A-\int_0^1 \dfrac{\log x}{1+x+x^2}dx\right)$

Let $C=\displaystyle 2\left[\int_0^1 \dfrac{x\log(x)}{1+x+x^2}dx-\int_0^1 \dfrac{x\log(1-x)}{1+x+x^2}dx\right]$

Therefore,

$C=\displaystyle \int_0^1 \dfrac{(2x+1)\log(x)}{1+x+x^2}dx-A-B$

$\displaystyle C=\left[\log(1+x+x^2)\log(x)\right]_0^1-\int_0^1\dfrac{\log(1+x+x^2)}{x}dx-A-B$

$\displaystyle C=-\int_0^1\dfrac{\log(1-x^3)}{x}dx
+\int_0^1\dfrac{\log(1-x)}{x}dx-A-B$

$\displaystyle C=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n}\int_0^1 x^{3n-1}dx-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n}\int_0^1 x^{n-1}dx-A-B$

$\displaystyle C=\dfrac{1}{3}\zeta(2)-\zeta(2)-A-B=-\dfrac{\pi^2}{9}-A-B$

Finally,

$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \dfrac{(1+x)\log\left(\dfrac{x}{1-x}\right)}{1+x+x^2}dx=\dfrac{1}{2}C+A=-\dfrac{\pi^2}{18}+\dfrac{1}{2}A-\dfrac{1}{2}B=-\dfrac{(\log 3 )^3}{8}-\dfrac{\pi\log 3 }{12\sqrt{3}}+\dfrac{\pi^2}{72}$

Comment: The computation of Chinny84 is not right according to me. The first change of variable wasn't performed correctly. My computation is however good but i'm affraid it's not related to the original integral :(

Comment: I'm affraid that none of proposed values are correct.

Comment: You are indeed correct about a mistake (it was right at the start) I will update accordingly.

Comment: @FDP see note for Chinny84,ok for the answer A(+1)

Comment: $-\frac{1}{8}\ln^23+\frac{\pi^2}{72}-\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{36}\ln3$ is correct indeed.

Comment: @FDP excellent work(+1)

Comment: Well, this answer is amazing

Comment: It took me 16 hours, non-stop, to achieve this computation. I was going nut.